What's the most effective way to hang a plastic egg tray under a kitchen cabinet?
We purchased this egg storage container to hold all our fresh eggs, and we want to mount it to the underside of a cabinet to get all the eggs off our counter. It's two drawers ini a box, all plastic. What's the best way to mount it? I can picture a couple ways:

Drill pilot holes through the top plastic and screw the box directly into the bottom of the cabinet, using washers to help distribute the weight. Would this risk cracking/breaking the box?
Frame a plywood box to screw into the bottom of the cabinet and slide the egg box in.
I'm picturing some kind of bracket solution, where four brackets dangle from the cabinet and hold the egg box. But I don't know how to look up the right shape of bracket for this...they'd have to be sort of z-shaped in order to drill into the cabinet.

What would you do?
Thank you!

Hang a (wooden) shelf there. Doesn't appear to need to be a particularly sturdy one to hold this. Plastic boxes have a nasty tendency to crack either when drilled or at some later time when stressed in ways the maker did not intend and design attachment points to accommodate.
The shelf can be literally hung (by screw hooks and chains, or long bolts) or spaced off the cabinet by wooden blocks screwed in place, as you prefer. Or it can be mounted to the wall with shelf brackets independent of the cabinet above.

Could use some plumbing strapping and strap it to the underside of a cabinet.

That would be incredibly fugly, @Huesmann.

Not that much uglier than screw hooks and chains.
